# Can we install SharePoint on Ubuntu 20.04.3 server,

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, linux

I am looking to install SharePoint on Ubuntu 20.04.3 server. Please suggest me if there a way.

Answer (score 1):

No. SharePoint 2013, 2016, 2019, and Subscription Edition servers must be run on some version of Windows Server.

[Software requirements for SharePoint Servers for SharePoint Server Subscription Edition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-requirements-for-sharepoint-servers-for-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition)

[Software requirements for SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019#software-requirements-for-sharepoint-server-2019)

[Software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements#software-requirements-for-sharepoint-server-2016)

[Software requirements for SharePoint Server 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-software-requirements-2013#software-requirements)